# *New Coder* Formatting and operators

Tags: c++, algorithm, operators, feed

Hi l just started learning *C++* and I have a program for a prompt :

- It goes along the lines of asking the user for inputs of their assignments one at a time and once they have no more inputs, the program must display `"Stop"`
- It must ask the user if they have more scores to enter once each score (boolean type)
- It must also obtain the average and place it on a scale of 100 and output the score associated, scale being: `A = 100-93`, `A- = 92-90`, `B+ = 89-87` etc

Below is what I have so far (please let me know if I can format it better for  compiler, I prefer to type in notepad)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Welcome to the Homework Point Sum Progam!"
  endl;
  cout << "How many assignments did you complete?:";
  endl;
  int assignments;
  int scores;
  int total = 0;
  int average = scores / assignents;
  cin >> assignments;
  // this next part I'm trying to find out how to set up the input for the assignments and have them line up as "assignment one, assignment two, etc."
  if (assignment > 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < assignment; i++) {
      else
        // I would like to know if this is a valid input and formatting of "else" as well as if my placement of it is valid

        cout << "Enter Assignment Score" << i << endl;
      cin >> scores

      total += scores
    }
  }
  if (average < 33)
    total += scores
  cout << "Fail" << endl:

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can format it better, but that's a thing any modern IDE or editor can do automatically. But I fear your question is off topic, since formatting is always opinion based. (Is this your actual question?) Code reviews are also off-topic, because there is a specialist forum for this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep adding other grades in the last lines using else if(your condition). If you want me to add anything else please tell me.

````
using namespace std;

int main(){
     cout<<"Welcome to the Homework Point Sum Progam!" <<endl;
     cout<<"How many assignments did you complete?:"<< endl;
     int numberOfAsssignement=0;
     int total =0;
     float average =0;
     cin >> numberOfAsssignement;
     cout << "Please enter your assignements results:";
     int assignements[numberOfAsssignement-1];
     for(int i=0; i < numberOfAsssignement; i++){
        cin >>assignements[i];
     }
     for(int i=0; i < numberOfAsssignement; i++){
        total +=assignements[i];
     }
     average = (total/numberOfAsssignement)*10;
     cout << average;
     if(average>=93) cout << "A";
     else if(average<93 && average >=90) cout << "A-";
     else if(average<90 && average >=87) cout << "B+";
}```
````

Comment: Thank you so much is there any way to add a question after every sequence in which a user enters their assignment, for instance:  after Assignment 2 ask is this the final assignment (yes/no) and continue based on the answer